# Developing a magento module for marketplace / multi vendor

Tags: magento, marketplace

I need a module that serves as a marketplace / multi vendor system for Magento. I searched on the web to see if I could buy one, and found some. One that got my interest was:
http://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Magento-Marketplace.html

But the problem with all of them was, they keep a unified catalog.

In my case, imagine that I would like to create a e-Commerce where there are a lot of pizza places, each pizza place with its own menu. With a unified catalog, the user would enter on the website, see all the pizzas, and when choosing from a pizza nearby, they may not have the kind that the user wanted.

So that's  why I wanted a module that first:
1. Show the places nearby;

1. Then, with a specific place selected,  show the catalog just for that place.
2. At first, when searching for products on the website, show the product and who is selling it, instead of just showing the product, as it is right now with this module mentioned above.

I thought of buying that module and write  code to fit to my needs:
1. Associating the product with the vendor who added it, and when showing the catalog for a vendor, show just the  products that he added;

1. Override the catalog search module. Showing instead  of all products, show the nearby vendors and a small list of  their products;

   but since I don't have access to the code of the module before buying, it may not be a good idea.... who  can ensure  that I will be able to perform those modifications?

So, short:
What is a best approach to develop such a module in Magento?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Lucas, did you buy this module? Can you tell me your experience with it? I found this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace.html

Comment: we are the developer of above extension for any query you can contact us at https://webkul.com/ticket/index.php thanks